# Boot from VHD with windows7 - bcdedit trouble

Tags: windows-7, boot, vhd

I'm running Windows7 Enterprise, x64 version. I've created a windows7 vhd file with help of the following blog post [hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StepByStepTurningAWindows7DVDOrISOIntoABootableVHDVirtualMachine.aspx)

After that, I've added it to my boot menu with help of another blog post [hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx)

This worked great.

After that, i've upgraded my hdd. With help of clonezilla i've copied the old disk to the new disk. Next step was to copy the vhd to another partition.

Then i updated the boot menu. However, the step

```
C:\>bcdedit /set {guid} device vhd=[driveletter:]\<directory>\<vhd filename>
```

fails with the message

```
An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
```

what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the problem is clear: the copying of my old hdd created  [dynamic disks instead of basic disks](https://superuser.com/questions/45779/dynamic-vs-basic-disk-hard-drives). [After changing this](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk) everything worked again.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Support's Native Boot VHD, but BCDedit does not Support Dynamic Disk, This error means that you have your VHD in a Dynamic Disk or Volume. You can Convert Your Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk in order to Continue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he found that out 2 years ago.

Comment: Ya, I know but there were too many negetive votes..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [EasyBCD 2.0](http://j.mp/EBCD2)? It has a new feature for automatically adding VHD entries to the BCD.

Comment: can't find anything about windows7 and vhd, are you sure that it solves my problem?

Comment: tried build 91. the feature is there, but doesn't work.

Comment: EasyBCD 2.0 final was released last week and fixes a lot of these problems.

http://neosmart.net/blog/2010/welcome-to-easybcd-2/